# Load and execute code from an assembly without locking the file?

Tags: .net, assemblies

Is there a way to load an assembly from disk and execute code in it without getting the file locked on disk?  I never understood why it is necessary to lock the file since the code will be loaded in RAM and JIT-compiled?

Comment: It's pretty much just a standard os feature to lock file based resources used by a process

Comment: @Pierreten: In Unix, you can unlink and replace shared libraries while they are in use. Because existing processes have an open file handle, the underlying inode won't get reaped until every process using the original .so file terminates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, you can use [Assembly.Load(byte[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h538bck7.aspx) to load an assembly as well.  That assembly doesn't have a "loading context", you can load it repeatedly.  Managing this is however not easy, you're bound to find out.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is called shadow copying. You have to create a new [`AppDomain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx) and provide an [`AppDomainSetup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.aspx) instance with the property [`ShadowCopyFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.shadowcopyfiles.aspx) set to the string `true`.

This application domain will copy the assemblies to a temporary location before loading them. See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279.aspx) for more details.